# Validate GET status of a url for mailchimp

Tags: php, api, callback, webhooks, mailchimp

I have created a function that creates a batch webhook in mailchimp so that a callback will be submitted once the batch operations is finished. like following:

```
// register mailchimp batch webhook
    $responseWH = wp_remote_post( 'https://' . substr($mcApi,strpos($mcApi,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batch-webhooks' ,array(
        'headers' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:'. $mcApi )
        ),
        'body' => json_encode(array(
                'url' => 'http://90660d72b8be.ngrok.io/wp-json/lubuvna/v2/batch/2810471250791421617231098394447326550803'
        ))

));
```

above code means, when a batch operation is finished MC should call this url:
`http://90660d72b8be.ngrok.io/wp-json/lubuvna/v2/batch/2810471250791421617231098394447326550803`

If this url is called, then a script will run and notify me that the operation is done und update the the post in wordpress.

but since the header status code is 404, mailchimp is not adding the url to the batch webhook.. instead i get following error:

```
{
    "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title": "Invalid Resource",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
    "instance": "05a4430f-c68f-46a5-82af-3b95332d6fe83",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "url",
            "message": "We couldn't verify the URL is working. Please double check and try again. HTTP Code: 500"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i return a 200 status in the header when Mailchimp is trying to make a GET request to the specified URL, while adding the batch webhook? they need a valid url. [mailchimp batch webhook](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/batch-webhooks/add-batch-webhook/)

I am using ngrok for connection within localhost which works when i add a URL like `http://90660d72b8be.ngrok.io/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/inc/batch/import.php`, because the file actually exist in the plugin directory

but when adding the URL `http://90660d72b8be.ngrok.io/wp-json/lubuvna/v2/batch/2810471250791421617231098394447326550803`

I can see that mailchimp makes a get request and the code status is 404 like in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: What 404 are you talking about here? According to the response from the API, they got `HTTP Code: 500` from your system, and that’s why this webhook URL could not be confirmed. So go and figure out _why_ your system responded with a 500.

Comment: @04FS I have edited my question. I can see that the GET request from mailchimp is showing '404 Not Found' in ngrok.. each time i run the add batch function, thats why the batch webhook is not getting added to mailchimp... only if i add a url with the script file like `wp-content/plugins/lubuvna-newsletter/inc/options/hooks/mailchimp/mailchim-script.php`

Comment: Well then you did not set up your endpoint to handle that request correctly.

Comment: @04FS and thats what i am asking here... How to handle the the request, so that mailchimp validate the url?

Comment: You are using the WP REST API endpoint here, so you need to _create_ you own custom endpoint for your action `batch` here first of all. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: I have created a route `/lubuvna/v2/` and an endpoint `batch`. The issue is clearly when MC makes a GET request and find nothing.. Although later if MC makes a POST requwst my script with the given url works fine... I need to valudate the url with 200 Code when mc makes a request

Comment: Then you probably set the endpoint up for method POST only, but not for GET?

Comment: Could you give me an example how to allow a get request with 200 status code in the header?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hav ended up using follwoing:

```
function myplugin_registered_rest_routes() {

    // batch operation finished
    register_rest_route('myplugin/v2', '/batch/(?P<id>\d+)', 
        array(
            array('methods' => ['POST', 'GET'],
                 'callback' => 'my_awesome_func'
            )
        ) 
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'myplugin_registered_rest_routes' );
```

another option of array like @04FS answer:

```
register_rest_route('myplugin/v2', '/batch/(?P<id>\d+)', 
        array(
            array('methods' => 'GET',
                 'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
            ), 
            array('methods' => 'POST',
                 'callback' => 'my_awesome_func'
            )
        ) 
    );
```

Another option parsing the url request. Not common when using wordpress API:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'register_endpoint', 0);

function register_endpoint() {
    global $wp;

    if ($wp->request == 'wp-json/myplugin/v2/batch/2810471250791421617231098394447326550803') {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        exit;
    }
}
```